# Will the JavaScript code be executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say that jQuery is enabled.

Will `alert(1)`, `alert(2)` be invoked?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="testDiv">
  <script>
    $('#testDiv').remove();
    alert(1);
  </script>
  <script>
    alert(2);
  </script>
</div>
```

I did some test on my own and figured out that the first alert will show up but not the second one. I am testing under Chrome. Just wondering what will happen for every other browsers. Can I expect the same behavior?

Comment: Sorry, let me edit it in case for misunderstandings

Comment: I have just done some old IE testing, as it turns out, IE9 and lower behave differently than modern browsers. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/7EpNj/

The first one will execute, as it will finish the first executing the first script tag, even though it has been removed from the DOM. The second script tag will not execute.

This is the expected behavior, and should be consistent across browsers.

**EDIT:** However, while the latest Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Internet Explorer (IE10) behave as expected, IE9 and below will actually fire both functions, even though both script tags are removed from the DOM.

```
<script>
    function func1(){
    alert("func1()");
}
function func2(){
    alert("func2()");
}
</script>
<div id="testDiv">
  <script>
    $('#testDiv').remove();
    func1();
  </script>
  <script>
    func2();
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

They shouldn't be. jQuery will execute `$("#test-div").remove();` first, before moving on to the next line. Removing `#test-div` will also remove all the markup and script inside it, which would therefore remove the calls to `func1()` and `func2()`.

Comment: `alert(1)` did show up.... http://jsfiddle.net/5ged6/1/ (I use 4 for 1 in this case)

Comment: Possibly because it's in the same `script` tag as `$("#test-div").remove();`... not entirely sure. Will have a look.

Comment: @Caolan: Yes, removing the `script` won't somehow *interrupt* an executing script. But it will prevent next `script` from being interpreted.